# error in running a function

Tags: javascript, shapes

I have to delete a shape in canvas.

The following code was written-

```
  function deleteCircle(circle, propName) {
      for( i = 0; i < circle.length; i++) {
        circle[i].erase();      
      }
    }
   circle.prototype.erase=function() {
      delete this;
    }
```

when i am running this code at i=0 it is going to the erase function. 
but after the frst delete it is not coming back to deletecircle.
This is just a rough code... i m just coonfused that after delete this.... that is after the object is deleted doest the code come back to deletecircle ?

Comment: I'd assume an error is occurring at `erase()` which is preventing the loop from continuing. Have you checked error logs?

Comment: You are modifying the length of the array inside the loop - this is a bad idea.

Comment: hey thr is no error. only 1 circle is getting deletd . i want the for loop to work till al the circles are deletd. but with this code. only 1 is getting deletd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other users have said, modifying size of your array during the loop is a bad idea. 
Try:

```
var circle = new Array();
circle[0]=1;
circle[1]=2;
circle[2]=3;
circle[3]=4;

function deleteCircle(circle, propName) {
    while(circle.length!==0){
        erase(circle.pop());
    }
}
function erase(elem){
    delete elem;
}

alert(circle.length);
deleteCircle(circle,null);
alert(circle.length);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SP9CD/)

**EDIT**: Sorry didn't notice you changed the code. Updated:

```
function circle(){};
circle.prototype.erase = function(){
    delete this;
}

var circles = [new circle, new circle, new circle];

function deleteCircle(circle, propName) {
    while(circle.length!==0){
        circle.pop().erase();
    }
}

function circle(){}; //or however you define your class
circle.prototype.erase = function(){ //extend the class
    delete this;
}

var circles = [new circle, new circle, new circle]; //your array

function deleteCircle(circle, propName) {
    while(circle.length!==0){
        circle.pop().erase();
    }
}

alert(circles.length);
deleteCircle(circles,null);
alert(circles.length);
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/SP9CD/)

Answer (score 0):

Your circle object doesn't have `erase` method. In your case `erase` is separate function and won't work like this.

Comment: i have made erase function in my circle object. i have edited the code . pls check